# attributeChangedCallback doesn't get called even after defining observedAttributes

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element

In the following code, attributeChangedCallback never gets called even if the 'content' attribute is created, changed or removed.

```
class Square extends HTMLElement {

    static get observedAttributes() {

        return ['content'];
    }
    constructor(val) {
        super();
        console.log('inside constructor');
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(document.createElement('button'));

        this.button = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('button');
        this.button.className = "square";

        this.content = val;

        console.log('constructor ended');
    }

    get content() {
        console.log('inside getter');
        return this.button.getAttribute('content');
    }
    set content(val) {
        console.log('setter being executed, val being: ', val);
        // pass null to represent empty square
        if (val !== null) {
            this.button.setAttribute('content', val);

        } else {
            if (this.button.hasAttribute('content')) {
                this.button.removeAttribute('content');
            }
        }

    }
    connectedCallback() {
        //console.log('connected callback being executed now');
    }

    // not working :(
    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
        console.log('attribute changed callback being executed now');
        if (name === 'content') {
            this.button.innerHTML = newValue?newValue:" ";
        }
    }
}
customElements.define('square-box', Square);
```

Based on the best practices given [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/best-practices), I want the side-effect of attribute change (updation of innerHTML in my case) to take place in attributeChangedCallback. However when I move this updation to the setter, the code works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set content(val) {
        console.log('setter being executed, val being: ', val);
        // pass null to represent empty square
        if (val !== null) {
            this.button.setAttribute('content', val);

        } else {
            if (this.button.hasAttribute('content')) {
                this.button.removeAttribute('content');
            }
        }

    }
```

**You are mixing up parents & children**

You are defining a *setter* on your Element **<square-box>** (►parent element)

When you do `this.button.setAttribute('content', val);`

You are changing a **attribute** of your **<button>** Element (►child element)

This will **never** trigger the `attributeChangedCallback` of (►parent) **<square-box>**
because **its attributes were not changed**

You either have to go "up the DOM" with [.getRootNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/getRootNode) and/or [.host](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot/host) to set *attributes* of **parent** elements.

or use [Custom Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) (bubbling up the DOM) to notify parents that children have done/changed something

**I presume you meant to do**

```
set content(val) {
        //  loose ==null comparison for null AND undefined, 
        //  element.content=null; will remove the attribute
        if (val==null) 
            this.removeAttribute('content');
        else 
        //  but you DO want .content(0) (0==false) set as "0"
            this.setAttribute('content', val);
    }
```

Comment: will calling the this.render() function inside setter affect the attributeChangedCallback()? @Danny

Comment: No only (predefined) observed attributes trigger the attributeChangedCallback